# How can I get the current location?

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the easiest and shortest method to determine the current location of the device in Android? An approximate, city-level location is good enough, and I need the Lat/Long coordinates, not the name. Think of weather location. But I'm using it for sunrise/sunset calculations.

All other examples here on StackOverflow and the web are at least a page long and rely on callbacks. But I'm in the middle of a watch face draw function and can't wait for callbacks. I just want to get the last known location that is certainly already lying around somewhere in memory.

One answer pointed me to `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()` but Android Studio says it doesn't know that method. So it's probably outdated and removed from more recent APIs.

I'm new to Android development and don't have a clue where to search. Web snippets brought me here but this time no further.

Comment: [It does appear to still exist](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)). Also, couldn't you periodically query the location in the background, store the result somewhere, and just read it when needed?

Answer (score 3):

> But I'm in the middle of a watch face draw function and can't wait for callbacks.

Frequently, you don't have a choice.

> I just want to get the last known location that is certainly already lying around somewhere in memory.

Frequently, it is not lying around in memory.

> One answer pointed me to LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation() but Android Studio says it doesn't know that method.

That method exists, as is seen in [the documentation for that method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)).

Since your question does not have the code that you are trying, it is difficult for anyone to help explain why that code is not compiling. Perhaps you are trying to call `getLastKnownLocation()` on the `LocationManager` class, rather than an instance of `LocationManager`.

Bear in mind that `getLastKnownLocation()` frequently returns `null`, as the device usually is not actively tracking the user location. Also, the user may have disabled location access, or the device might be in airplane mode (and so has no access to non-GPS sources), or the device might be in a facility that leads to crappy signals (e.g., large parking structures), etc.

You could also use the Play Services' [fused location provider](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), but it requires a callback.

Comment: I'm following the fused location provider sample but `LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient` wants an Activity (which I don't have) or a Context (don't know what that is). I have a service instead (derived from `CanvasWatchFaceService`).

Comment: @ygoe: [`Context` is a Java class in the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). `Service` inherits from `Context`. So, you should be able to pass a `Service` to `getFusedLocationProviderClient()`.

Answer (score 1):

Being in the middle of a watch face draw function or not should not make a difference.
Most of the snippets you will find on the web will indeed tell you to use callbacks. Not because it's "ok" in some cases, but because it **is** how the system works.

### On a high level :

You'd let the system know that you're interested in the location of the device.

---

The system then starts computing information.

---

When a position has been determined, and then every-time the location changes significantly enough (as defined via accuracy), the system will let you know what the actual position of the device now is (through these callbacks).

### My recommendation :

Start implementing this logic when the watch face renderer is created. Have the option to display a "location not known" (as @CommonsWare mentioned, location can be unavailable for a bunch of different reasons). And have your proper way (eventually) of storing the last know location (SharedPref sounds like a good option).

Answer (score -2):

add these permissions to your manifest.xml

implement LocationListener in your activity, a method from this class will give you updates on the android devices location as it changes

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}
```

call this startGettingLocations method in your oncreate method of the activity so that all permissions needed can be requested from the user

```
private void startGettingLocations() {
        Log.i("Process", "start getting locations");
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean isNetwork = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        boolean canGetLocation = true;
        int ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT = 101;
        long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 100;// Distance in meters
        long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 10 * 6 ;// Time in milliseconds

        ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest;

        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);

        //Check if GPS and Network are on, if not asks the user to turn on
        if (!isGPS && !isNetwork) {
            showSettingsAlert();
        } else {
            // check permissions
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0) {
                    requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]),
                            ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                    canGetLocation = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.i("Permissions", "fine loc not granted");
        } else{
            Log.i("Permissions", "fine loc granted");
        }

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.i("Permissions", "coarse loc not granted");
        } else{
            Log.i("Permissions", "coarse loc granted");
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        //Starts requesting location updates
        if (canGetLocation) {
            if (isGPS) {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

            } else if (isNetwork) {
                // from Network Provider
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't get location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```